# Socket error WSAEACCES "An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions" on Private/Home network

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-10, winsock2

I'm getting this error (WSAEACCES) when calling ***connect*** function on a TCP socket (destination address is a laptop on the same local network) with my Wifi network profile set as private/home.
When I set it to public, no error.
I tested with ports above 1024, checking they were not already used, running program as Administrator, disabling Firewall, creating a specific FW rule....Nothing works !
I checked other answers for this error message but none worked or apply to my case.

I compiled the [Microsoft Client Source code sample](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/complete-client-code) found in Winsock2 documentation and I get the same results: works when wifi network profile is set as public but not when set to Home/Private.

Using Windows's telnet client works in all cases, so I'm wondering if is a privilege matter (telnet.exe security properties includes 'TrustedInstaller' which has all rights granted) or something related to a missing clause in the manifest file (like private network client server capability for UWP applications). Or perhaps a Windows configuration issue...
Environment : Windows 10 Pro 21H2, x64 app.

Thanks for your help !

The link above contains a complete code snipped that demonstrate the problem so I thought it was wasteful to repeat it here....anyway here is an even shorter sample code :

```
int TestConnection()
{
  //----------------------
  // Initialize Winsock
  WSADATA wsaData;

  int iResult = WSAStartup( MAKEWORD( 2, 2 ), &wsaData );

  if ( iResult != NO_ERROR )
  {
    wprintf( L"WSAStartup function failed with error: %d\n", iResult );
    return 1;
  }

  //----------------------
  // Create a SOCKET for connecting to server
  SOCKET ConnectSocket;
  ConnectSocket = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_TCP );
  if ( ConnectSocket == INVALID_SOCKET )
  {
    wprintf( L"socket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

   //----------------------
   // The sockaddr_in structure specifies the address family,
   // IP address, and port of the server to be connected to.
   sockaddr_in clientService;
   clientService.sin_family = AF_INET;
   clientService.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr( "192.168.1.2" );
   clientService.sin_port = htons( 23 );

  //----------------------
  // Connect to server.
  iResult = connect( ConnectSocket, (SOCKADDR*) &clientService, sizeof( clientService ) );

  if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR )
  {
    wprintf( L"connect function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    iResult = closesocket( ConnectSocket );

    if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR )
        wprintf( L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
    WSACleanup();
    return 1;
  }

  wprintf( L"Connected to server.\n" );

  iResult = closesocket( ConnectSocket );

   if ( iResult == SOCKET_ERROR )
   {
      wprintf( L"closesocket function failed with error: %ld\n", WSAGetLastError() );
      WSACleanup();
      return 1;
   }

    WSACleanup();
    return 0;
}
```

Here is some clarifications :

- no use of a broadcast address,
- bind is not used

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] demonstrating the problem. Don't just link to some external code and expect us to figure it out. The [`connect()` documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winsock2/nf-winsock2-connect) says: "*WSAEACCES An attempt to connect a datagram socket to broadcast address failed because setsockopt option SO_BROADCAST is not enabled.*" But that only applies to UDP, not to TCP...

Comment: The [Winsock error code documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/winsock/windows-sockets-error-codes-2) says: "*Another possible reason for the `WSAEACCES` error is that when the `bind` function is called ... another application, service, or kernel mode driver is bound to the same address with exclusive access. Such exclusive access is ... implemented by using the `SO_EXCLUSIVEADDRUSE` option.*" The fact that Telnet connects means TCP is working fine, so there has to be a problem with how your code is using `connect()`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added sample code.